# Use part of string in DF

Tags: python, pandas

Please a need to return a part of string

I have this (example):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'vals': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'ids': ['XXX2100M', 'yyyy2100M', 'AAA850M', 
    'BBB2100M']})
```

My goal:

```
  vals        ids    test
0    1   XXX2100M   2100M
1    2  yyyy2100M   2100M
2    3    AAA850M   
3    4      2100M   2100M
```

Modify `['test']` just if i have '2100M' on string.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `np.where` with `str.contains`:

```
import numpy as np

df['test'] = np.where(df.ids.str.contains('2100M'), '2100M', '')
```

---

```
print(df)

   vals        ids   test
0     1   XXX2100M  2100M
1     2  yyyy2100M  2100M
2     3    AAA850M       
3     4   BBB2100M  2100M
```

Answer (score 1):

using `str.extract` which accepts a regular expression as an argument

```
df['test'] = df['ids'].str.extract('(2100M)').fillna('')

print(df)

   vals        ids   test
0     1   XXX2100M  2100M
1     2  yyyy2100M  2100M
2     3    AAA850M       
3     4   BBB2100M  2100M
```